# g++ libc.so absolute path cross-compiling error

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cross-compiling

I am cross-compiling on an ubuntu pc for an arm target using the gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-4.8-2013.07-1_linux tools.

If place the libc.so from the target in the library search path the linker errors with:

**cannot find /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6**

If I remove this libc.so then the linking process finishes with no errors.

It seems like there might be a symlink to an absolute path in the libc.so library.  Is this why I get the linker error?

If yes is there a way to modify the symlink?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and mostly solved it.

The problem is, that some so files contain no linkable code, but contain a ld linker script. If this linker script contains absolute references, then the linking will fail.

I write a small perl script, that convert all symbolic links to relative links and also patches the so linker scripts to relative path.

That works by hand quite good, the automated process generates a tar file with perl - without making changes at the raspberry file system.

The tar will be unpacked on the host in the sysroot folder and all links are fixed and all so files are fixed to.

```
less /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
```

and you will see that:

```
/* GNU ld script
Use the shared library, but some functions are only in
the static library, so try that secondarily.  */
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-littlearm)
GROUP ( /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc_nonshared.a  AS_NEEDED ( /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 ) )
```

Just with the first test I found that tar will convert all relative links to absolute ones but if I list the tar file everything is relative correctly.

[Tar changes relative symlinks to absolute symlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49582114/tar-changes-relative-symlinks-to-absolute-symlinks)

Comment: What directory do you make it relative to? I tried making it relative to the linker script libc.so but then it just said: cannot find ../../../lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 instead.