# Tar changes relative symlinks to absolute symlinks

Tags: linux, tar, symlink

To simplify the sysroot generation for cross compiling, I generate a tar file with relative symbolic links.

If I print the tar context with

```
tar tvf sysroot-libc6-dev.tar
```

then I get the correct result:

```
lrw-r--r-- jens/jens         1 2018-03-30 23:42 usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libBrokenLocale.so -> ../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libBrokenLocale.so.1
lrw-r--r-- jens/jens         1 2018-03-30 23:42 usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libanl.so -> ../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libanl.so.1
lrw-r--r-- jens/jens         1 2018-03-30 23:42 usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcidn.so -> ../../../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcidn.so.1
```

If I unpack the tar archive with

```
tar xvf sysroot-libc6-dev.tar
```

then the symlinks are absolute, this is a mess, because then the sysroot directory points to my host machine  and cross compile will not work.

```
ls -al

lrwxrwxrwx 1 jens jens      33 Jan 14 11:39 libanl.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libanl.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jens jens      42 Jan 14 11:39 libBrokenLocale.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libBrokenLocale.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jens jens      34 Jan 14 11:39 libcidn.so -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcidn.so.1
```

The purpose of the script is to keep everything relative, also the linker scripts, e.g. libc.so will be patched to relative links.

Thanks in advance

Jens Riebold

Comment: So you want to make the unpack work like the print, right?

Comment: That's right. When I place relative links in the tar file, I expect that tar unpacks the archive without modifications

Comment: The tar file is generated on the raspberry pi with a perl script. This script changes the symlinks in the tar file to absolute ones and also modifies the ld linker scripts with relative locations. That makes the cross compilation very easy. The perl script makes the modifications only in the tar file, so I cannot break my pi.

Comment: Add tar version and perl script to your question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem of my post. The tar will set relative links only if the destination of the symbolic link is also in the tar archive.

The problem with cross compiling for the raspberry pi are the absolute symbolic links to the libraries and the absolute paths in the ld scripts. (SO Files).

If you copy prebuild libraries from the raspberry pi into your cross compile project, then you have to fix that. It took me some time to understand the strange linker issues while working on my project.

The project works as follows:

```
sync_package.pl <debian package name>
```

The output is a tar file with relative links and relative pathes in the ld scripts.

Example:

```
sync_package.pl libmodbus-dev
```

Output:

```
sysroot-libmodbus-dev.tar
```

Comment: I uploaded the script to
https://github.com/jensriebold/raspberry_crosscompile_tool